# Thunar freezes when moving many files through terminal

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, thunar

I am running Xubuntu 21.10 with Thunar 4.16.8. The latter will freeze every time in the following situation:

1. In Thunar, go to directory `foo`. The directory has 100k+ files.
2. With terminal, move the files (or delete them) from the `foo` directory. This takes less than a second.

Voile! The Thunar is now frozen. It might take minutes for it to recover, it may never come back to life. Killing given Thunar window closes all instances. I should mention the issue does not happen when small number of files is present.

Does it sound like a Thunar bug? Or perhaps it's something about my setup? I could not find any errors that would point at the problem (e.g. `dmesg`), but then maybe I was looking at wrong places. The problem is present both on SSD and NVMe drives.

Comment: I've seen the same issue using Mint 20 XFCE using Thunar 1.8.14. Also see the issue with smaller number of files but adding and deleting many times. e.g. scripts that need to use temp working files. Thunar doesn't seem to be able to handle a lot of file changes that happen quickly (for the current folder being shown). Open thunar to /tmp then run the shell script below. Any other thunar windows not showing /tmp will start to be sluggish. Nemo and Caja don't have this problem. All 3 file managers show similar CPU usage when testing this: https://pastebin.com/tc5b5uYW